# Copying a column into another dataframe based on matching columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have two data frames. The data frames are different lengths, but have the same IDs in their ID columns. I would like to create a column in  `df` called `Classification` based on the `Classification` in `df2`. I would like the `Classification` column in the `df` to match up with the appropriate `ID` listed in `df2`. Is there a good way to do this?

```
#Example data set
library(lubridate)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2011"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)
ID2 <- rep(seq(1,5), 1)
Classification2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df2 <- data.frame(ID2, Classification)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution using `left_join()`.

```
left_join(df, df2, c("ID" = "ID2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a merge between df and df2?  Assuming Classification is a column in df.

```
df2 <- merge(df2, df, by.x = "ID2", by.y = "ID", all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: The problems is that Classification isn't part of df. The data frames are also different lengths. I'm trying to get the Classification into df2 based on the ID that it is associated with in df. Is there a way to do that?